# Why some payment methods allow being embedded in an iframe and some don't?

Tags: authentication, credit-card, credentials, iframe, payment-gateway

Let's take some examples:

1. Pay Pal, Apple Pay ([examples via Saferpay](https://saferpay.github.io/sndbx/CssiFrame.html#css-info)) - will not load in an iFrame
2. Visa Checkout, Stripe ([example](https://www.paymentiframe.com/)), Saferpay (link above) - credit card data can be input in an iFrame

Is there any technical/security reason why payment service providers differ in their approach to restricting iframe usage for credentials/payment information input? Or this is simply difference in risk management (and its supporting technologies for fraud prevention), business decision or maybe a legacy (and non-secure) integration architecture?

Comment: The company I work for supports paypal, applepay, googlepay, etc from within an iframe. It just takes more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One contributing factor may be that PCI SSC rewards use of iframes by granting [SAQ A](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_A_v3.pdf) status to merchants who use it, lowering the number of audit requirements down to a bare minimum.  That would explain why you see it more commonly with credit cards, although as @Bobson pointed out many alternative payments also support iframes.

Comment: PCI promotes a method that is inferior in terms of security to a redirect? Wow.

Comment: @user2530062 - No, it says it's equally secure (they're both SAQ A).  In both cases, the merchant's website is providing a URL to the browser, and the browser loads the payment page from - and submits it back to - the card processor's website.  Whether it's all contained inside a self-contained iframe or whether it redirects the parent page doesn't change that.